# Why can't we have 'star' for the answers?

Tags: feature-request

I'm simply loving this site. Thanks a ton to the makers. While almost all features are useful, I think it lacks one more feature -favoriting the answer the same way we do for the questions.

At times, though a question is normal, its answer is explained beautifully and it deserves to be bookmarked for us for further reference. For questions, it is possible to 'star' it but then for the answers, there is no option.

One way to make it happen is 'star' the question but then what if the question has several answers. It'll be again time consuming to find out which one we liked a lot. Furthermore, if the question is so general, 'starring' it is against our own volition! :)

Comment: I "star" bad questions rather frequently. Just my opinion, but I regard upvotes as the main way to praise a question, while "favoriting" a question simply means I want to be able to find it again – for better or for worse (noteriety isn't always a good thing). Sometimes I'll favorite a question when I request further information, just so I can go back later and see if the O.P. provided it. In any case, this question really belongs on SE meta, since you're proposing a format change that would affect all SE sites.

Comment: There is a work around. Create a folder in your browser bookmarks, and bookmark the share link. Answers don't have titles like questions do, but I usually want to have a more descriptive title so I find it works out better than favoriting the question.